# Unable to change TextView size on button click, why?

Tags: android, button, textview, text-size

Hello guys right now I'm working on an app in which there are many quotes, in a `TextView` and I want to change the size of `TextView` on button click, like if Small button is clicked then the `TextView` should become small, if Large is clicked it should be large, etc. But each time I press the `Button` app force closes! What's the problem? Here's `OnClickListener` for the `Button`:

```
small = (Button) findViewById(R.id.small);

small.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quotes);
                tv.setTextSize(20);
            }
        });
```

P.S: The `TextView` and the `Button` are in different `Activities`.

Comment: TextView and Button are in different Activities ? Then it's not going to work because findViewById is hooked to layout of one Activity.

Comment: Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Please include more information. For example, it is possible to change what happens in one activity from another through using Intent.putExtra, LocalBroadcastManager and an EventBus library. It is also possible to set something like preferred font size in SharedPreferences. It all depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the `TextView` size by `Button` from one `Activity` in other `Activity`. You will get `NullPointerException` because the findViewById method will not find view and will return null. You should use `SharedPreferences`. You should save text size value when you click `Button` and read it in the second `Activity`.

In your setting Activity:

```
   small.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this.getBaseContext());
            sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putFloat("FONT_SIZE", 22)
            .apply();
        }
    });
```

In your activity where you have TextView

```
     TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quotes);
     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this.getBaseContext());
     tv.setTextSize(sharedPreferences.getFloat("FONT_SIZE", 13/*DEFAULT VALUE*/));
```

Comment: Is there any solution for that? Please tell me because from 2 months I'm developing this app...Thank You very much!

Comment: You can also set your value in some singleton but your issue sounds like some setting. If you want to create something like setting it is a right solution

Comment: so this solution is right for you. Do you know how do this? I can give you some example if you want

Comment: Oh Thank you very much!!! I really appreciate if you give an example :-) Give me an example and I'll definitely accept it!